# How to speedup the unzip process in Powershell using 7zip.exe

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I am using 7zip exe to unzip the files in powershell script which was taking a lot of time to do simple work (almost 45 min to 1 hr 30 min for 32 files). Is there any other alternative?

Here is the code below:

```
Set-Alias sz "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"

sz x $zipfilename -o"$unzipfolder" -y
LogWrite "$zipfilename unzipped to $unzipfolder successfully"
```

Comment: Is the operation any faster if you run it from a batch file? I would expect not. I don't see anything in your (incomplete) code snippet that would cause PowerShell to slow down the execution of an external program. How large are the archives, and how many files are you extracting (approximately)?

Comment: Files are on avg 500mb p/f....total 32 count

Comment: Well, extracting 16 GB of compressed data is going to take a while. Nothing PowerShell can do about that.

Comment: The same extraction  with batch script unzip has done lessthan 2 mins...but my entire script was in powershell and if I have to use my powershell variables  in bat script I'm calling to unzip..will work ?
Thanks alot for ur answers

Comment: Hmm... 1 hour vs. 2 minutes is quite the difference. Is that just one file or all 32 as well? Like I said, I don't see anything in your PowerShell code that would explain that kind of slowdown.

Comment: Yea, there is nothing wrong but may be 7zip exe was the one causing  issue.. is there any other exe which can extract  the same format?

Comment: There are lots of tools able to extract zip archives (like WinZip or WinRar). PowerShell v5 or newer even has a cmdlet for that ([`Expand-Archive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/expand-archive)). However, 7-zip works really well in my experience, so I wouldn't expect the problem to be on that side either. Maybe some antivirus interfering?

Comment: You can investigate ceveral things from here on but Powershell is not one of them. I would in descending order look at `taskmanager/process explorer/resource monitor` while unzipping and **verify** your CPU is getting used *(ideally 100%)*. If it is, my next step would be to use `procmon` and look in the stacks window for anything unusual. If that doesn't hint you at something, I'd try `WPA`. Using `WPA` gives you a very high guarantee to find the problem *(if there is one!)* but it takes practice in analyzing the wealth of information it provides.

Comment: I was trying to unzip the files from a network  based shared folder and writing  them to a temp folder in the same location.

Comment: Please go through, there is some solution. https://github.com/PowerShell/Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive/issues/32

Answer (score 2):

You can use [.NET API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile.createfromdirectory?view=net-6.0) directly in powershell instead of using a third-party tool.

```
Add-Type -Assembly "System.IO.Compression.Filesystem"
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory("C:\installers\app.zip", "C:\installers\app")
```

Source: https://github.com/PowerShell/Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive/issues/32#issuecomment-668732081

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue where my file was around 6 GB and later i switched to [7 zip PowerShell module](https://www.sans.org/blog/powershell-7-zip-module-versus-compress-archive-with-encryption/)
and i see nearly 6X improvements.